# Book trilogy about twins in a walled city where people are sorted by intelligence

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I remember reading this great trilogy series about 10-15 years ago. It's about a family living in a dystopian walled city where people are sorted and classed by their intelligence.

The protagonists are twins, a boy and girl. They defy the system and are exiled from the city, along with another boy. They journey across a desert and have many adventures etc. This is only in the first book.

I remember the cover being a big 'S' shaped symbol. It had something to do with a wind chime that was central to the plot.

Edit:
There is already another question with the same answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/looking-for-a-book-series-about-a-girl-and-her-friends-captured-and-sold-as-slav). I did do a search on stackoverflow before I posted this question of course, but I feel I would never have know it's the same question just looking at the title. It's up to the community to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Twins, Basil! Twins!

Comment: Don't be offended by the fact that your question was closed as a dupe; it's still a good question. We just have [a policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) that story-ID questions are always dupe-closed if both questions have the same accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with the policy, and I'm not offended. I hope my question would be able to help others with the same question, but that are not able to find the original one.

Comment: Yup. And that's how it works and why we encourage people to post answers even if they think that the question might be a duplicate, or that there's already a highly voted or even accepted answer, because someone later on might do a search and find the book they're looking for. You'll still get upvotes as people find the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[The Wind Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind_Singer)*

[image: Book cover with symbol]

(Emphasis is mine)

> *The Wind Singer* is a young adult novel written by William Nicholson. It is the first book of the Wind On Fire Trilogy. It follows the quest of **twins** Kestrel and Bowman Hath, and their friend Mumpo to restore the "**Voice of the Wind Singer**" to their city and bring happiness to their cruel society.

....

> The book begins in the **walled city** of Aramanth, an extreme **meritocracy** where endless **exams and ratings** are the only way to move forward to improved life stations; to be unsuccessful in this is seen as a great source of shame.

....

> Using an archaic map given to her by the Emperor [Kestrel] sets off, joined by her twin brother, Bowman, and their brave but pitiful new friend, Mumpo, who has an unshakeable affection for Kestrel. They meet a variety of tribes and individuals including the fearsome **nomadic clans** of Ombaraka and Omchaka.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! It's been on the tip of my tongue for so long.

Comment: It took a few iterations of Google searches before I saw http://courses.wcupa.edu/johnson/220novels-new.htm and noted the title mentioned twins, wind, and a repressive city, so I looked up more details and found a match. :)

Comment: Thanks, I did try google, but clearly I didn't search hard enough

Comment: It's often a matter of finding just the right set of terms. :) Biggest trick is finding ways to exclude the wrong results and the "TOP 1000 S-F BOOKS YOU MUST READ B4 U DIE!!!111!!!" lists.