# Fantasy novel with colored districts

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book about 10 years ago, in French, but I don't know if it was a translation or the original language.

The story takes place in a big city, where each district is painted in a different colour.
And the colour depend of the wealth of the people living in it.
For example, the poorest peoples lives in the Grey district, in small appartments.
But richest peoples lives in the Yellow district (I am not really sure of this colour...), in big villas.

About the story in itself, I remember that we were following a teenager (male I think but not sure), from the Grey district.
He ends up going into the Yellow district and encounter another teenager (female I think but not sure).
At some point they had to ran away, and went in a large underground passage, and maybe went out of the city.
And maybe they encountered a big monster at some point, but I can't tell for sure.

Anyone know about this book?

Comment: Is it one of [these](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/16ikaw/tomtbook_city_divided_in_to_coloured_districts/?st=j3k6u2u9&sh=76375e67)?

Comment: Yes, I think it's this one! I don't understand how I did not find this link ^^" And I did not remember that it was a trilogy... I read only the first.

Comment: I was going to suggest "Shades of Grey" by Jasper Fforde; it sounds exactly like it.

Comment: pre-existing duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/looking-for-a-book-series-about-a-girl-and-her-friends-captured-and-sold-as-slav

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Could it be [*The Wind Singer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind_Singer) (*Les Secrets d'Aramanth*)?

[image] [image] [image]

It's the first book of the [*Wind on Fire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_on_Fire) (translated to French as [*Le Vent de Feu*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Vent_de_feu)) trilogy by William Nicholson, published in 2000 - 2003. I have not read the books myself, but it was mentioned in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/16ikaw/tomtbook_city_divided_in_to_coloured_districts/), and the Wikipedia description is more or less in line with yours.

The main characters are Kestrel and Bowman, and they live in a city called Aramanth. It does indeed have colour separation based on merit *all emphasis mine):

- "different colour"

  > Using a system based on colour classifications, the governing Examiners dictate what people can wear, where they can live and what jobs they can do. **The levels are grey, maroon, orange, scarlet and white, with grey the lowest and white the highest.**

  Or from another [webpage](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/3648463/Readers-notes-The-Wind-Singer.html):

  > The book tells the story of how a sister and brother (Kestrel and Bowman Hath), and their stinky classmate Mumpo, dare to challenge the oppressive social order that operates in the walled city of Aramanth.
  >
  > Under this system, families can move up and down the social scale depending on their children's success (or otherwise) in school examinations, and on the parents' success (or otherwise) in their careers. High achievement brings not just prestige, but promotion up the **colour-coded, socio-economic ladder - from the low-rent tenements of Grey District up through Maroon, Orange and Scarlet to the very topmost district of all, ie White.**
- The go on an adventure, and eventually confront some evil creatures:

  > This sets in motion a chain of events that eventually results in Kestrel, Bowman and a mentally challenged boy called Mumpo **escaping from the city and going on a quest to save their people from an evil entity known as the Morah**, which controls a numberless army of malevolent and deadly beings called the Zars.

Comment: Thanks! And for those who are searching its French title it's : "Le Vent de feu" (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Vent_de_feu)